# Soft hyphens with DirectWrite API

Tags: directwrite

In a sample application DWriteSimpleHelloWorld I render a text

```
wszText_ = L"Hello World using Direct\u00ADWrite!";
```

to a DWrite `HwndRenderTarget` -- effectively, to a window of my application. I render text with a `DrawText` method of `ID2D1HwndRenderTarget`.
I expect a behavior conformant to a rendering of text strings containing entity `&shy;` (soft or syllable hyphen) in web browsers.

If a window is wide enough to fit the width of the rendered phrase, I see a text like

```
Hello World using DirectWrite!
```

But when I resize my window so that the tail of a phrase fails to fit into the window, I see :

```
Hello World using Direct
Write!
```

while web browsers would render this text with a hyphen at the end of a first line:

```
Hello World using Direct-
Write!
```

My purpose is to let users insert hyphenation hints for long words in my `DWrite` application, but what I see is as if `\u00AD` works as a "hidden" whitespace.

I have read of subtleties concerning a soft hyphen definition and usage (for example, https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/shy.html), so I humbly ask : is the observed behavior of `DWrite` "by design"? If so, how one can implement hyphenation hints that would produce hyphens at the end of lines when needed?

Notice that when I use glyph indices of my `wszText_` string to draw text as a geometry created with a method `GetGlyphRunOutline` of `IDWriteFontFace`, I see a string containing a hyphen in its due position:

```
Hello World using Direct-Write!
```

Comment: @Bertrand Martel: thanks for formatting my text.

Comment: I finally tested this myself, and I can confirm, on Windows 8.1 SHY acts as breaking point, but does not produce visible hyphen. I would say, if you need to render them you'll have to implement layout logic yourself.